# Can I autorun Data Mask when creating a new sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, data

The challenge I have is that I need to be able to mask data in my Salesforce sandbox as soon as its created, is it possible to get the Data Mask app to run when the s/box is being created?

Comment: To the best of our knowledge, as of now this is not possible out of the box. You'd have to reverse-engineer the name of the job that gets scheduled when you click Run on data masking app/tab and use [SandboxPostCopy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171550/sandboxpostcopy-functional-failure)

Comment: This might not be possible (https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DqOzAAK)